# Create a function that selects a Main Menu bar based on the selected tab

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I am fairly new to c++ and am wondering if there is a way to create a function that will select a menu bar created in the MFC Menu Editor and display it at the top of the window.

[image]

The idea is to have a different menu bar for each of the tabs because each tab will have different options.

For example a menu bar called ID_REGMENUBAR for Doom Reg and ID_SCRIPTMENUBAR for the Script

If more info is needed please say so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CMenu::LoadMenu` and `CWnd::SetMenu`. For example, declare member data:

```
CMenu m_menu1, m_menu2;
```

Initialize the menu once:

```
m_menu1.LoadMenu(ID_REGMENUBAR);
m_menu2.LoadMenu(ID_SCRIPTMENUBAR);
```

Use `SetMenu(&m_menu1)` to assign the menu on run time. You can respond to tab selection changes by looking `TCN_SELCHANGE`

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(...)
    ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB1, OnTabSelection)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyWnd::OnTabSelection(NMHDR*, LRESULT*)
{
    int tab = m_Tab.GetCurSel();
    CMenu *pMenu = NULL;
    if (tab == 0) pMenu = &m_menu1;
    if (tab == 1) pMenu = &m_menu2;
    CFrameWnd* frame = (CFrameWnd*)AfxGetMainWnd();
    frame->SetMenu(pMenu);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement that and I can see it runs the SetMenu(); using a breakpoint but it does not change the menu bar. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Document interface model? MDI/SDI etc.

Comment: Single Document Interface. I actually just discovered I had put it in the wrong spot. I am able to get it to change the menu bar now i am just trying to work it in so it changes based on the selected tab